# Likelihood Ratio Test explanation

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

Attached is a problem I am trying to do for revision[image]

It's mostly bookwork I've done that. What worries me are parts b) (iii) and c).

Could you help me with the interpretation of the likelihood ratio statistic and the graphs? What I know is that $\Lambda$ will converge in distribution to $\chi_{1}^2$ so that we can compare the result with the given values. For part c) we can conclude that both graphs pass through the point $(\lambda_{0},\alpha)$, if we plot the power against the value of $\lambda$. We also have by the NP lemma that $w_{a}(\lambda)> w_{b}(\lambda)$ for $\lambda > \lambda_{0}$